# What type of fiber connection is this?

Tags: ethernet, fiber

I have a Cisco 2950 switch at home with the same fiber port in this picture.  Can anyone tell me what type of port this is?  LC, SC, FC, MTRJ?  I am new to fiber optic ethernet.  I'm pretty sure this connection is using a multimode cable.  Looking to purchase a fiber cable to use in my home network stack of Cisco switches.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: That is an mtrj port and yes it's multimode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the comment above, it's indeed an MT-RJ connector.  I also know it's multimode because 1000base-SX is MMF-only.  Lastly, you can even make a very educated guess about the type of fiber based on the colors of the strain relief boot at the connector and the jacket/protective cover of the main cable.  In your case, orange with a beige boot is another indication of MMF (OM1 or OM2.)

[image]

Comment: How did you know it is 1000base-SX from the picture?

Answer (score 1):

It's a MTRJ connector. Besides, the supported module is 1000BASE-SX, and it's true that this is multi-mode cable, since 1000BASE-SX is only designed to work over MMF. Certainly, the color of this cable also show it's multi-mode version.